# HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start - Application '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\xxxxx\' failed to load coreclr

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have a web Api that works fine in many Azure Windows Server, but there is one of them that it says: HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start.  Just watching the event viewer of the server I saw the message error: Application '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\xxxxx' failed to load coreclr.

I made all things that Microsoft and another people with the same issue, but the issue continues.  Please is there anyone who knows what it could be?

Comment: Run a report to rule out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the attribute value of hostingModel in the configuration file is OutOfProcess. If the value of the hostingModel property is InProcess, try to change it to OutOfProcess and start the project again.